# How to use structure from one c file in another

Tags: c, data-structures

is it posibble in C, that you define a structure in one .c file, but use it in another?
Basically, I would like to use my List that I have already created in another program. But I would like to use diffrent structures.

I've 3 files:

main.c -- another program, where I want to use the list

list.c -- code of the list

head.h -- header to bind them

In main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct cell{
int x;
cell next;
}TCell;

typedef struct{
TCell first;
int lenght;
}List;

#include "head.h"

int main()
{
TCell *c
c->x = 5;
List *l;
init(l);
add(l,c)
c = get();
return 0;
}
```

head.h:

```
#ifndef HEAD_H_
#define HEAD_H_
void init(List *l);
void add(List *l, TCell *c);
TCell get();    
(...)
#endif
```

list.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "head.h"

typedef struct{
TCell first;
int lenght;
}List;

void init(List *l){ (...) }
void add(List *l, TCell *c) { (...) }
TCell get() { (...) }
(...)
```

But when i try to compile it, it doesn't work, because it is missing the TCell in head.h and list.c, and the List in head.h

So, is there a possibility to have just one definition of TCell in the main.c, so whenever i change its inner variables, it will still work?

Comment: Put the *structure* in the header file as well?

Comment: You should define your `struct`-s and `typedef`-s in your common `head.h` header

Comment: How are you building? Can you e.g. show the gcc command line you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make this your `head.h`:

```
#ifndef HEAD_H_
#define HEAD_H_

typedef struct cell
{
    int  x;
    cell next;
} TCell;

typedef struct
{
    TCell first;
    int   lenght;
} List;

void init(List *l);
void add(List *l, TCell *c);
TCell get();    

...

#endif
```

And remove the `typedef` of `List` and `TCell` from `list.c` and `main.c`, because you only need to define a type once.

Header files are meant to contain your shared type definitions.

Here's an [entry of the famous C-FAQ](http://c-faq.com/cpp/hfiles.html) that may help.  I advise you to read through this whole FAQ it will teach you a lot of things about C and will save you a lot of time.

Comment: Seems to work now :). Thx a lot

Comment: @Martafix Great, thanks for letting me know. C takes a while to get used to. Really, have a good look a this C-FAQ I mention.